# lift template and snippet returning slick query result

Tags: lift, slick

Please excuse if this is a very basic question, I'm learning. :(

I have this class:

```
class X  {
  def do_something {
    db withSession {
      val qresult = for { 
         (d, o) <- TABLE1 innerJoin TABLE2 on (_.TB1ID === _.TB2ID)
      } yield(d, o)
    }
  }
}
```

and I would like to build a HTML table out of this, something like:

```
(record1)  d.TB1ID d.F1VALUE d.F2VALUE o.F1VALUE o.F2VALUE o.TB2ID
(record2)  d.TB1ID d.F1VALUE d.F2VALUE o.F1VALUE o.F2VALUE o.TB2ID
....
```

would anyone be kind enough to give me a pointer where to look? I've found plenty of examples but I have trouble connecting the `qresult` value to something I can bind in my template.

I am using Lift and Slick 1.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a table in your HTML template that looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="TB1ID"></td>
    <td class="dF1VALUE"></td>
    <td class="dF2VALUE"></td>
    <td class="oF1VALUE"></td>
    <td class="oF2VALUE"></td>
    <td class="TB2ID"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then, you should be able to have your CSS Transform look like:

```
"tr" #> qresult.map { case (d, o) =>
  ".TB1ID *" #> d.TB1ID &
  ".dF1VALUE *" #> d.F1VALUE &
  ".dF2VALUE *" #> d.F2VALUE &
  ".oF1VALUE *" #> o.F1VALUE &
  ".oF1VALUE *" #> o.F2VALUE &
  ".TB2ID *" #> o.TB2ID 
}
```

That will key on the `TR` and repeat it for every row in your `qresult` list. Then, for each of the columns (represented above by their `class` attribute), it will output the value you want associated with it. Note that the `*` in the selector will append the value on the right as a child of the `TD` instead of replacing it with the value on the right.

You can find more information on CSS Selectors and outputting HTML here:

- http://simply.liftweb.net/index-7.10.html
- https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/binding_via_css_selectors

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work. Apparently I had to call .list on the qresult before using your example above, but otherwise it seems to be working great. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, how would you do this if I wanted to have a template within a template? For example, assume that d.F2VALUE above was an array of n pictures, so I want to insert n pictures into the table cell identified by .dF2VALUE?

Comment: Essentially you'd do it the same way as you handled the TR row above: `.dF2VALUE *" #> d.F2VALUE.map{ n => ".ele" #> n.value }`. If you have a more specific example you want to see, just post a new question and I can give you a more complete answer.

Comment: thanks! i am going to try to figure it out on my own before bugging ya.

Comment: Well,I got stuck at how to aggregate the items that have duplicate keys :( If you have time, my new question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173423/lift-grouping-items-during-css-selector-transform